# Copy file from tmux pane (or window) dir to another pane (or window) dir

Tags: tmux, cp

Example:

2 panes.

Pane 1 current dir: `/a/b/c/d`

Pane 2 current dir: `/a/f/g`

I want to copy `file.csv` in current dir of pane 1 to current dir of pane 2.

What I do:

In pane 1:

```
cp file.csv ../../../f/g
```

It's slow and annoying to find the right relative path from the dir in pane 1 and I feel I could just "drag and drop" the file from one pane to the other.

Is there a way to do something analogous to a drag an drop?

Example of a "good" solution:

```
cp file.csv $pane2dir
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following in my tmux.conf

```
# get directory from other pane using xsel
bind J run-shell -b -t bottom "echo -n #{pane_current_path} | xsel -i"
bind K run-shell -b -t top "echo -n #{pane_current_path} | xsel -i"
bind H run-shell -b -t left "echo -n #{pane_current_path} | xsel -i"
bind L run-shell -b -t right "echo -n #{pane_current_path} | xsel -i"
```

Often the pane that I want to copy to is to the left or right of my current pane. If it is to the right I would do `<prefix> shift-l` to put the current directory of the right pane in the clipboard.

To sort of satisfy your solution requirement one could modify this to create a command such as:

```
cp file.csv $(tmux run-shell -b -t right "echo -n #{pane_current_path} |xsel -i" && (sleep 0.01; xsel -o))
```

It would make sense to put that stuff in a shell script for convenience.

After giving my answer I played around a little bit and came up with the following

```
bind L if-shell -b -t right "tmux set-buffer -b panedir #{pane_current_path}" "paste-buffer -db panedir"
```

which puts the current directory of the "right" pane directly on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you replace `right` with `:.+` it copies from the next pane. With two panes (Norton Commander / Midnight Commander-like configuration), this is the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I use [tmux-yank](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank) plugin for this. It has the feature for copying pane current working directory to system clipboard. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin.)

To provide full answer to the question, here are the steps I do with this plugin:

- navigate to tmux pane 2, yank pane working dir to clipboard
- navigate to tmux pane 1, start typing the command and just paste the path where you need it with `ctrl-v` or `Cmd-v` on Mac

Comment: Could you give more information of how to yank the pwd of the active pane, please? I was already using your plugin and wasn't aware of this functionality. I went to the github repo of the project and saw the new commits with the message talking about this. According to the repo readme, I yank the pwd with `prefix + Y` but it doesn't work. In my tmux active bindings there's no entry for `bind-key Y`. Should I add one for `tmux-yank/scripts/copy_pane_pwd.sh` manually? Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes, this is a new feature for `tmux-yank`. `prefix + shift + y` should do the work, plug-n-play, no manual configuration necessary. If you already have the plugin installed, I suggest updating it (`prefix + shift + u` with `tpm`). If for some reason `bind-key Y` is still not defined, please open an issue for the plugin and I'll look into this.